# Ignorar um slug ao clicar no link

Tags: php, wordpress

Exemplificando, tenho a seguinte url de exemplo:

> dev.google.com/members/usuario/profile/activity/mentions.

```
echo ( '<li id="' . $user_nav_item->css_id . '-personal-li" ' . $selected . '><a id="user-' . $user_nav_item->css_id . '" href="activity/mentions">' . 'Menções' . '</a></li>' );
```

Percebam que no href, tenho "activity/mentions"

Como faço para quando o usuário clicar no link ele não passe pelo profile.

A confirmação da pergunta é: Como ignorar aquele profile quando o usuário clicar no link?

E fazer

> dev.google.com/members/usuario/profile/activity/mentions.

Virar isso

> dev.google.com/members/usuario/activity/mentions.